# Is there a benefit of using IsDefined over GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Consider the case where an assembly contains one or more types attributed with a custom attribute `MyAttribute` and you need to get a list of these types. Is there any benefit of using [IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.isdefined.aspx) vs. [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88d17d13.aspx) aside from the more compact syntax? Does one expose/hide something that the other doesn't? Is one more efficient than the other?

Here is a code sample demonstrating each usage:

```
Assembly assembly = ...
var typesWithMyAttributeFromIsDefined = 
        from type in assembly.GetTypes()
        where type.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false)
        select type;

var typesWithMyAttributeFromGetCustomAttributes = 
        from type in assembly.GetTypes()
        let attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false)
        where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
        select type;
```

Comment: It would take trawling through lots of classes to answer this question definitively, but yes, there are (slight) performance considerations between a method that returns a bool and a method that returns a new array (the singular `GetCustomAttribute` goes through `GetCustomAttributes`).  Looking at the code, it appears that the costs are more significant than just that difference, though as always, you should profile to determine whether this is a difference you care about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Done a quick test with the two methods and it seems `IsDefined` is a lot faster than `GetCustomAttributes`

200000 iterations

```
IsDefined average Ticks = 54
GetCustomAttributes average Ticks = 114
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: and then you remember it's ticks and realize that it doesnt really matter that much after all

Answer (score 3):

As Saddam demonstrates, `IsDefined` is more efficient than `GetCustomAttributes`.  That's to be expected.

As [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653983.aspx), applying attribute `MyAttribute` to class `MyClass` is conceptually equivalent to creating a `MyAttribute` instance.  However, the instantiation does not actually occur unless `MyClass` is queried for attributes as with `GetCustomAttributes`.

`IsDefined`, on the other hand, does not instantiate `MyAttribute`.