# Where did Attribute.IsDefined go in DNX Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm trying to check if a property has an attribute. This used to be done with:

```
Attribute.IsDefined(propertyInfo, typeof(AttributeClass));
```

However I get a warning that it's not available in DNX Core 5.0 (it still is in DNX 4.5.1).

Has it not been implemented yet or has it moved like other type/reflection related stuff?

I'm using beta7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:**
There actually seems to be an `IsDefined` extension method in the [`System.Reflection.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Extensions) package. Usage:

```
var defined = propertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(AttributeClass));
```

You need to include the `System.Reflection` namespace. The reference source code can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.Extensions/ref/System.Reflection.Extensions.cs#L43). Beside `MemberInfo`, it works on `Assembly`, `Module` and `ParameterInfo` too.

This is [possibly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719104) than using `GetCustomAttribute`.

---

**Original post:**

Looks like it's not ported to .NET Core yet. In the mean while you can use `GetCustomAttribute` to determine whether an attribute is set on a property:

```
bool defined = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AttributeClass)) != null;
```

You could bake this into an extension method:

```
public static class MemberInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAttributeDefined<TAttribute>(this MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        return memberInfo.IsAttributeDefined(typeof(TAttribute));
    }

    public static bool IsAttributeDefined(this MemberInfo memberInfo, Type attributeType)
    {
        return memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute(attributeType) != null;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
bool defined = propertyInfo.IsAttributeDefined<AttributeClass>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It always returns null. `GetCustomAttributes` doesn't contain my attribute at all.

Comment: @SaphuA I added an example. Can you show what your code looks like?

Comment: Whoops guess you're right! Not sure what I did wrong in my test... Thanks!

Comment: Is this way is as fast as Attribute.IsDefined ??? it does not have any overhead ??