# GetCustomAttributes vs GetCustomAttributesData

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get custom attributes from a property.  I've been using [`GetCustomAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes) for this but I've recently read that `GetCustomAttributes()` causes an instance of the attribute to be created and [`GetCustomAttributesData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata) just gets data about the attribute without having to create an instance of the attribute.

With this in mind, it seems like `GetCustomAttributesData()` should be faster because it doesn't create an instance of the attribute.  However, I'm not seeing this expected result in tests. When looping through the properties in a class, the first iteration has `GetCustomAttributes()` running about 6ms and `GetCustomAttributesData()` running about 32ms.

Does anyone know why it takes `GetCustomAttributesData()` longer to run?

My primary goal is to test for the existence of an attribute and ignore any property containing this attribute. I don't particularly care which method I end up using and I'm not really concerned with what either method returns apart from understanding why `GetCustomAttributesData()` is slower than `GetCustomAttributes()`.

Here's some sample code I used to test with. I tested each of these if statements independently by commenting out one and then the other.

```
public static void ListProperties(object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoCollection = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propertyInfoCollection)
    {
        // This runs around 6ms on the first run
        if (prop.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>().Count() > 0)
            continue;

        // This runs around 32ms on the first run
        if (prop.GetCustomAttributesData().Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(MyCustomAttribute)).Count() > 0)
            continue;

        // Do some work...
    }
}

public class MyCustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

---

Just a little while ago, I decided to try the [`IsDefined()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined) method after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719104/is-there-a-benefit-of-using-isdefined-over-getcustomattributes) post. It seems to be faster than both `GetCustomAttributes()` and `GetCustomAttributesData()`.

```
if (prop.IsDefined(typeof(MyCustomAttribute)))
    continue;
```

Comment: The question here is what those methods are returning. You seems don't care about this in your test, but I am quite sure custom attribute instance is not the same thing as [`CustomAttributeData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata(v=vs.110).aspx). How you going to use that?

Comment: Documentation of that `GetCustomAttributeData` suggests to "Use this method to examine the custom attributes of code in the reflection-only context, in cases where the custom attributes themselves are defined in code that is loaded into the reflection-only context". I'd personally follow this recommendation.

Comment: "My primary goal is to test for the existence of an attribute and ignore any property containing this attribute." Maybe use `IsDefined` instead then? `if (prop.IsDefined(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true))` (or `false` if you don't want inheritance involved)

Comment: I've edited my question.  Thanks @JonSkeet for the suggestion.  I will use IsDefined().

Comment: Inheritance will not work in your example, @JonSkeet. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38565778/2157640
Either static methods of System.Attribute, or extensions from System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions have to be used.

Answer (score 7):

Well `GetCustomAttributesData` also creates instances of new objects, just not of the attributes themselves. It creates instances of [CustomAttributeData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata(v=vs.110).aspx). This class has mainly information about the attribute type but also about the constructor and the constructor arguments and even the names of the constructor arguments.

These properties have to be set using reflection wheras creating the attribute instance is just a standard object creation. Of course it all depends on how complex the constructor of your attribute is, although in general I have rarely seen complex attributes.

Thus calling `GetCustomAttributesData` gives you more/different information about the attribute than `GetCustomAttributes` but is (for simple attributes) a more costly operation.

However if you intend to call `GetCustomAttributesData` multiple times on the same `MemberInfo` object it could be faster since reflection calls are usually cached. But I didn't run a benchmark on this, so take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: thanks for the information on GetCustomAttributesData().  I didn't realize another objec was being created.  I've updated my question and decided to go with IsDefined().